# Call edit action after selecting value in dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The edit view page has the following dropdown:

```
<%= select_tag "Voiture", options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicles, :id, :model, params[:id].to_i) %>
```

When used, I would like to reload the page with the `Vehicle` chosen in the dropdown. I don't know whether to use `:onchange => submit()` or `:action => 'edit'`. Thanks.

Comment: Try using: `select_tag :voiture, options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicles, :id, :model, params[:voiture]), :onchange => "$(this).closest('form').submit()"`

Comment: It's not working. Same behaviour : the page calls the update action. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: is this working for you using HTML and JS? and you just need to make it dynamic?  take a look at http://pullmonkey.com/2012/08/11/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails-3/ this should really help you out

Comment: I didn't try anything with JS. It is not important whether or not it is dynamic.

Comment: I think you need to give more details about what you want to happen when someone chooses an option from the select.  Are you actually saving anything?  Or are you just loading different options for the edit page?

Comment: All of this is occurring in the Vehicles controller. You can access  all of the Vehicles' ids inside the dropdown. If you select one, it reloads the page with the chosen Vehicle. In order words, edit_vehicle_path(chosen_id_from_dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a form like this(which is common for edit & new action)
and dynamically we are assigning ID to this form, hence for edit action this forms id will
Be `'edit_customer_form'`

```
  #_form.html.erb 
<%= form_for(@customer, html: {id: params[:action] + '_' +'customer_form'}) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :vehicle_id %><br>
    <%= f.select  :vehicle_id, 
       options_from_collection_for_select(@vehicles, :id, :name) %>
  </div>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now, we want when the value in the selection box is altered the edit form(#edit_customer_form) should get submitted.

```
 #application.js

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#edit_customer_form').on('change', '#customer_vehicle_id', function(){
   $('#edit_customer_form').submit();
 });

});
```

Here `#edit_customer_form` is the edit forms ID and `#customer_vehicle_id` is the ID of the selection box. 
Check the complete code in below gist link:

https://gist.github.com/AjayROR/0a633ee493d78ff30332

Comment: The code is working, but it's still calling the update action. Is it impossible to call the edit action again?

Comment: Initially when you open the form it's in edit action only, then when you change the value from dropdown you wanted to submit it, so it's hitting the update action.

Comment: If just selecting a value from vehicle dropdown is your motive then you can just comment out the javascript codes. Because the form itself is in edit action :p

Comment: I guess I don't have the choice, I will have to redirect the user from the update action. Thanks!